# How to send a packet immediately

Tags: c, sockets, networking

I use Linux C to write a simple socket program. (Both client & server side)
When server got a packet from client. Server will send a response packet to client.

When client send continuous packets, I expect server send back resp. packets within 100ms. However, the time of resp. packet send back sometimes over 300ms.

[send packet not immediately](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6q58F.png)

I try to used disable NAGLE algorithm.

```
setsockopt(serverTcpSockId, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, &reuse_flag, sizeof(int));
```

or disable send buffer

```
setsockopt(serverTcpSockId, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, &nZero, sizeof(nZero));
```

Both these two methods not work.

Comment: Did you do this at both ends? What did `setsockopt` return? Did you time the *code* itself, comparing the timestamps with Wireshark?

Comment: Have you tried to clear TCP_CORK along with setting TCP_NODELAY ? I remember when i had the same problem I done both.that is i set tcp_nodelay and cleared tcp_cork

Comment: To Antti : I only add setsockopt on server side.

Comment: To Shihab : I will  try to clear TCP_CORK, thank for your comment

Comment: @CloudLee you can reply to people like this.

Comment: @CloudLee Please comment if your problem is solved, So that it will help others.

Comment: This problem is solved, it is not TCP problem. It's related to printf function. Since I will output log to terminal. I guess print function will queue message. After turn off this function is work well.